# Matching two different agent types by their properties in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have agents of two types in Netlogo (firms and workers) and they are connected through a common identifier, that, however, is an agent property (called ID for Firms, and FirmID 
for workers). 
I am interested in asking firms to display their workforce by performing an ask for firms, asking them to display a count of all workers such that the workers' "firmID" variable equals the firms "ID" variable, as described below:

I have tried to ask firms to count all workers such that the workers ID firms equals the asking firms' ID, but that is not working inside an ask procedure. If I try one by one, curiously it does work.

some reproducible toy code:

```
breed [Firms firm]
breed [Workers worker]
Firms-own[
 ID
] 

Workers-own[
 FirmID
]

to agent-creation
create-workers 3; There are 3 workers
create-firms 2; There are 2 firms
  ask worker 0 [set FirmID "333-1"]
  ask worker 1[set FirmID "333-1"]
  ask worker 2[set FirmID "444-1"]
  ask firm 3 [set ID "333-1"]
  ask firm 4 [set ID "444-1"]
end
; Thus, firm 333-1 has 2 workers, 444-1 has only one.
```

and now,

```
to matching-procedure
  ask firms [show count workers with [FirmID = [ID] of self]]
end
```

does not work, but

```
ask firms with [ID = "333-1"][show count workers with [FirmID = "333-1"]]
```

does.

The procedure should output [2 1] (I will put the result in a list, but clearly the idea is that firm 333-1 has 2 workers and 444-1 just one)
So Firm 333-1 should declare 2 and 444-1 just one.

Comment: It makes sense that I got an error, as I am mixing variables of different agent types, but still an idea of how this could be done would be good...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very common to mix up `self` and `myself`, which is what you have done here. Try:

```
to matching-procedure
  ask firms [show count workers with [FirmID = [ID] of myself]]
end
```

The reason you need `myself` is because the variable ID belongs to the firm, which is the agent doing the asking. In contrast, `self` is the one being asked. So your original code generates an error letting you know that workers don't own the attribute ID.

That fixes your problem. Just as a general comment on linking together firms/workers or other one to many relationships in NetLogo, it is best to avoid using identifiers and simply store the agent. That would look like this:

```
breed [Firms firm]
breed [Workers worker]
Firms-own[
 my-workers
] 

Workers-own[
 my-firm
]

to agent-creation
  clear-all
  create-firms 2; There are 2 firms
  create-workers 3
  [ set my-firm one-of Firms
  ]
  ask Firms
  [ set my-workers workers with [my-firm = myself]
  ]
end

to check-allocation
  ask Firms [show my-workers]
  ask Workers [show my-firm]
end
```

Another option commonly used is to create a `link` between the firm and worker. Links are the natural way to express a relationship, and can be hidden so they don't clutter up the visualisation.

Comment: Gr8! I was missing that little snippet of code, which made all the difference! :) Many thanks, it works like a charm. Good tip for the future, thought kind of irrelevant for this particular project, as I already have thousands of lines using this conceptualization. But I think you are right, it does make more sense to use some kind of network rather than identifiers..